# Control+f Search

Tags: chrome, text-search

I am trying to search a page that has tons of bolds,sub,sup,spans and italics on the page for text formatting(think math and chemistry equations).

Unfortunately in Chrome there appears to be no way to search this document such that the values overlap among the searches.  For example if I highlight and copy the text it is "4 a c" but actually searching the page terms up nothing.

I am currently using [Chrome Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn) but it doesn't seem to highlight the text either.

Comment: Why not inspect page source and see what the actual HTML looks like. You can search the DOM tree directly.

Comment: @xji I could probably make my own but this is a softwarerecs not programming site.